# Does the variation in android attribute naming styles mean anything?

Tags: android, attributes, naming-conventions

It looks like the naming style for android attributes varies between underscore and camel case. Does the variation mean anything, or is it arbitrary?

edit: examples would be *layout_width* and *columnWidth*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any semantic meaning behind the style difference.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me :) Thanks.